# C#: how to show list from custom class objects in a combobox

Tags: c#, list, class, combobox

this is my class:

```
namespace LAN_index_program
{
public class LAN_object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LAN_object(
        DEVICETYPE a_type,
        string a_deviceName,
        string a_deviceManufacure,
        string a_deviceOwner,
        string a_deviceIp,
        string a_deviceMac,
        DateTime a_deviceInstalationDate
        )
    {
        m_deviceType = a_type;
        m_deviceName            = a_deviceName;
        m_deviceManufacure      = a_deviceManufacure;
        m_deviceOwner           = a_deviceOwner;
        m_deviceIp              = a_deviceIp;
        m_deviceMac             = a_deviceMac;
        m_deviceInstalationDate = a_deviceInstalationDate;
        Name = a_deviceName;
    }

//        public string a_deviceName
//        {
//            get
//            {
//                return m_deviceName;
//            }
//        }

    public enum DEVICETYPE
    {
        Router,
        Switch,
        Access_point,
        Laptop,
        Phone,
        Computer
    };

    public string toString()
    {
        string lan_onbjectstring = "";

        lan_onbjectstring = m_deviceType.ToString() + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring +=  m_deviceName + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring += m_deviceManufacure + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring += m_deviceOwner + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring += m_deviceIp + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring += m_deviceMac + "\r\n";
        lan_onbjectstring += m_deviceInstalationDate.ToShortDateString() + "\r\n";

        return lan_onbjectstring;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_deviceName;
    }

    DEVICETYPE m_deviceType;
    string m_deviceName;
    string m_deviceManufacure;
    string m_deviceOwner;
    string m_deviceIp;
    string m_deviceMac;
    DateTime m_deviceInstalationDate;
}
}
```

and this is the code i thought would do it:

```
m_listLanObjects = new List<LAN_object>();

        comboBox1.DataSource = m_listLanObjects;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = null;
```

every time i add an new LAN_object to the list i reset the datasource to m_listlanobjects. but the combobox is not filling up.

```
namespace LAN_index_program
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_listLanObjects = new List<LAN_object>();

        comboBox1.DataSource = m_listLanObjects;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = null;

    }


    public void AddLanObject(LAN_object a_newLanObject, LAN_object a_oldlanobject, bool New = true)
    {
        if (New)
        {
            m_listLanObjects.Add(a_newLanObject);
        }
        else
        {
            int index = m_listLanObjects.IndexOf(a_oldlanobject);
            m_listLanObjects.RemoveAt(index);
            m_listLanObjects.Insert(index, a_newLanObject);
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.Text = listToString();
        comboBox1.DataSource = m_listLanObjects;
    }
}
}
```

i would like to choose an lan_object from it's name (m_deviceName). and at the press of a button want to use that specific Lan_object in further functionality.

hope someone can help, google for once did not help.

Comment: i have added the code. this will only happend when a dialog is finised. just an fill-in form for all the members of the class. m_listLANobjects is declared in "public form1{ ... }"

Comment: the whole code with the snippets is uploaded. hope u can help because no one thusfar could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep as much of your current code the same as possible, you'll have to set the `DataSource` to `null` first, then set the `DisplayMember` again (because it gets erased), *then* set your `DataSource` again.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataSource = m_listLanObjects;
```

An easier way to do it would be to use a `BindingList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, as that will update your `DataSource` automatically without having to reset the `DataSource`.

You'd declare the `BindingList` as follows:

```
private BindingList<LAN_object> m_listLanObjects = new BindingList<LAN_object>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource {DataSource = m_listLanObjects};
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Then just add items to the collection and they'll show up in the `ComboBox`.